# All Unique Permutations - Stack overflow issue

Tags: java, algorithm, stack-overflow

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Given a collection of numbers that might contain duplicates, return
>   all possible unique permutations.

Here is my code:

```
public class Solution {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> permute(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Boolean> unique = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        permu(results, a, 0, unique);
        return results;
    }

    private void permu(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> results, final ArrayList<Integer> a, int item, HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Boolean> unique) {
        for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> aClone = new ArrayList<>(a);
            // swap
            int backup = aClone.get(i);
            aClone.set(i, aClone.get(item));
            aClone.set(item, backup);
            if(!unique.containsKey(aClone)) {
                results.add(aClone);
                unique.put(aClone, true);
                permu(results, aClone, i, unique); //<--- Stack overflow error
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have a stack overflow error on this the call to the recurrence, line (19)

Comment: Could you write a comment next to the line where the stackoverflow error happens? It's not very practical for us to be counting line numbers here.

Comment: sure > permu(results, aClone, i, unique);

Comment: question edited

Comment: You're starting from 0 every time. I think you mean to do `int i = item;`.

Comment: This is for some kind of coding contest, right?  The trick will be that one of the tests includes one integer that occurs *many* times... probably so many times that generating and checking all n! permutations would time out even if it didn't overflow the stack.

Comment: yes, it is training for future job interviews ;) I wonder if it could be the fact that I am using a recurrence as well, thus using more memory

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't like to ruin good job interview questions, but this question was fun to think about, so...

Here's a super-L337 answer for generating all unique permutations very quickly and without using much memory or stack.  If you use this in a job interview, the interviewer will ask you to explain how it works.  If you can do that, then you deserve it :)

Note that I permuted the chars in a string instead of the instead of integers in a list, just because it's easier to pretty-print the result.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Consumer;


public class UniquePermutations
{
    static void generateUniquePermutations(String s, Consumer<String> consumer)
    {
        char[] array = s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(array);
        for (;;)
        {
            consumer.accept(String.valueOf(array));

            int changePos=array.length-2;
            while (changePos>=0 && array[changePos]>=array[changePos+1])
                --changePos;

            if (changePos<0)
                break; //all done

            int swapPos=changePos+1;
            while(swapPos+1 < array.length && array[swapPos+1]>array[changePos])
                ++swapPos;

            char t = array[changePos];
            array[changePos] = array[swapPos];
            array[swapPos] = t;

            for (int i=changePos+1, j = array.length-1; i < j; ++i,--j)
            {
                t = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        generateUniquePermutations("banana", s->{
            if (line.length() > 0)
            {
                if (line.length() + s.length() >= 75)
                {
                    System.out.println(line.toString());
                    line.setLength(0);
                }
                else
                    line.append(" ");
            }
            line.append(s);
        });
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
aaabnn aaanbn aaannb aabann aabnan aabnna aanabn aananb aanban aanbna
aannab aannba abaann abanan abanna abnaan abnana abnnaa anaabn anaanb
anaban anabna ananab ananba anbaan anbana anbnaa annaab annaba annbaa
baaann baanan baanna banaan banana bannaa bnaaan bnaana bnanaa bnnaaa
naaabn naaanb naaban naabna naanab naanba nabaan nabana nabnaa nanaab
nanaba nanbaa nbaaan nbaana nbanaa nbnaaa nnaaab nnaaba nnabaa nnbaaa
```

Comment: thank you Matt, I will take a deeper look at this, do you think the recurrence in my approach is causing the issue like I was thinking about?

Comment: BTW, yes it's a pretty fun problem, I think as well

Comment: @JeromeAnsia, when you call permu recursively, you should pass `item+1` instead of `i`, and stop the recursion when item>=a.size().  You should also start the for loop at `i = item`.  The way you wrote it, you are recursing infinitely with the same arguments